# how do I extract the 2 sub element of every part of a list even when some parts don't have a second sub element?

Tags: r, list

I have names in a list and each part of the list has 1 to 16 names in it. the list format is below.

```
[[1]]
[1] "Peter A. Christensen" "Mathis Eskjær"        "Peter Lyngby"        
[4] "Mikkel Poppelhøj"    

[[2]]
[1] "Aleta Doroudian" "Bill Briles"    

[[3]]
[1] "Aleta Doroudian" "Bill Briles"    

[[4]]
[1] "Aleta Doroudian" "Bill Briles"    

[[5]]
[1] "Barry Humphries" "David Dimbleby" 

[[6]]
[1] "Annie Sprinkle"  "Phillip B. Roth"
```

I want to extract the second name in each section of the list but some sections have only one name which breaks the `lapply(LIST, "[[", 2)` way of doing it.

How do I fix this problem?

I've tried `lapply(LIST, "[[", 2)` but it breaks on a part that only has one name.

Comment: Using `sapply(LIST, "[", 2)` adds `NA` if no value is found.

Comment: `lapply(LIST, head, n = 2)` works as well, returning no more than two elements (optionally 1). Which to use `head` versus `\`[\`` depends on what you want in the return: if you want a one-long vector to return length-2 (second is now `NA`), then use `[`; if you want only 1 in the return, use `head`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).